# Multiline UILabel and UITextView using Storyboards, Auto Layout and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uilabel, autolayout

I am trying to add a Multiline UI Label as a header followed by a UITextView as the content body.

I have added the UILabel and UITextView as follows:-

[image]

The Label has number of lines set to 0, character wrapping and standard left, right, bottom and top constraints. I have also set a minimum height constraint but that does not seem to change anything. The UITextView below it has a top constraint to the label and left, right and bottom constraints to the view/layout guide.

The actual output is this:-

[image]

There should be 3 lines for this label but it is showing only 2 lines/

[image]

This label should have 2 lines and the text as "Tricyclic anti-depressants" but the last line is not visible.

Is there anything wrong with my setup/constraints?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you are setting preferredMaxLayoutWidth on both labels. Can you try reducing the max layout width by... say, 10 points for the title label? I've had a hunch lately that there's a bug with iOS 8 with this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have not set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth for either of the controls. Do I need to set that or can everything be done using storyboards?

Comment: With iOS 8 there is a new section in the interface builder where it can be set; however, it usually does not need to be set - it should work automatically. If I am right, though, and this is a bug with preferredMaxLayoutWidth you will need to set it in layoutSubViews. After calling [super layoutSubViews] do something like `label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = label.frame.size.width - 10`. See if that works.

Comment: Turns out it is a bug with iOS. I just set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth as lbl.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.view.bounds.width and it is working perfectly. Thanks for all your inputs. Please write your comment as a separate answer so that I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do these two things:

1. Increase the number of lines of the label
2. Set the Height Constraint to greater than or equal

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. My height constraint is already greater than or equal and I tried increasing the number of lines to 3 but it did not help.

Comment: Make sure you have the bottom constraint of label to the Textview

Comment: Hi, my label's bottom constraint is set to the textview. Actually I did not add a bottom constraint to the label but I added a top constraint for the textview so it added a bottom one for the label as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the top label's Vertical Compression Resistance priority is higher than the textview.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I set vertical and horizontal content compression resistance was set to 750 by default for both controls. I changed the vertical compression of the label to 1000 but that did not solve it. I forgot to mention but the label does not show the complete text even if I delete the textview.