# How to break lines In UILabel?

Tags: ios

I am trying to assign a text to the `UILabel` in `UIViewController` and my text is :

**Get As Many Questions Right As You Can! Get A Questionn Wrong. And You Will Loose A Life! Lose All Three Lives And It's Game Over!**

But when I insert it into label it looks like :

[image]

I try to set **Lines = 4** Like this way :

[image]

But its not working and my output should look like :

[image]

How can I achieve that? Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add line break for UILabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312899/how-to-add-line-break-for-uilabel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:-

Add it to a TextView instead of a UILabel

Option 2:-

Change the number of lines in your UILabel to 0, set the auto layout constraints properly and set preferredMaxLayoutWidth as follows:-

```
lbl.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.view.bounds.width
```

Comment: Check my previous question for more help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988087/multiline-uilabel-and-uitextview-using-storyboards-auto-layout-and-swift

Comment: Glad I could help. Look at option 2 later on too because if you use a custom cell in a TableView that has a label, you should know how to make that label multiline if needed!

Comment: sure I will check it later

Answer (score 0):

- Do `label.numberOfLines = 0;` to allow for any number of lines.
- Try to add `\n` where you need a line-break.
- Update the label size to match the text size:

  CGSize labelSize = [label.text 
                      sizeWithFont:label.font
                      constrainedToSize:label.frame.size
                      lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];

  label.frame = CGRectMake(
                           label.frame.origin.x,
                           label.frame.origin.y, 
                           label.frame.size.width,
                           labelSize.height);